# Item not deleting from sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sharedpreferences

I have a list that I saved in sharedpreferences I want to delete an item from the listview when the user longclicks so on the long click the app prompts you with a question to delete or not when you confirm it deletes it. This works but when i come back to the activity the list still contains that item that has been deleted
This is the code for the onCreateView. tinyDB is sharedprefrences.Thank you

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_secondsemester, container, false);
    btnAddNew = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewYearOneSecondSemester);
    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewSubjectsMyCoursesSecondSemester);
    tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext());
    storedList = new ArrayList<>(tinyDB.getListString("storedList"));
    generalList = new ArrayList<>();
    spinnerValues = new ArrayList<>();




    getActivity().setTitle("Year One");

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),R.style.DialogeTheme);
            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Add new");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            String getUsername = tinyDB.getString("Username");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Hello "+ getUsername + ", please write the new subject");
            final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f06292"));
            alertDialog.setView(input);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String getSubjectInput = input.getText().toString();
                    storedList.add(getSubjectInput);
                    tinyDB.putListString("storedList", storedList);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
            new SweetAlertDialog(getContext(), SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Delete")
                    .setContentText("Are you sure you want to delete this course")
                    .setConfirmText("YES")
                    .setCancelText("NO")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                            storedList.remove(i);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            tinyDB.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
                                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                            sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                            sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });


    arrayAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getContext(),storedList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this when the user deletes it

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
    mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size());
}
```

mDataset is the array/list in which you save all the data for the adapter

Comment: please what is the notifyItemRemoved(position); and the notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size());

Comment: @EmmanuelOkocha Look it up in the **DOCS**, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int))